# Запуск одного окна один раз

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать, чтобы нельзя было открыть окно, если оно уже открыто?

Comment: Распишите свою задачу и проблему более подробно, сейчас это звучит слишком многозначно.

Comment: А что мешает наложить этот констрейнт в бизнес-логике?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень просто.
Создаёте переменную boolean

```
Boolean WindowOpened = false;
```

При запросе на открытие окна проверяете, равна ли переменная false, если равна - открываете окно и присваиваете переменной значение true:

```
if(!WindowOpened){
    OpenWindow();
    WindowOpened = true;
}
```

Comment: У меня много окон, можно как-то по-другому сделать?

Comment: Много окон - много переменных, для каждого окна - своя переменная.

Comment: Или создайте массив...

Comment: Просто больше переменных и проверок = больше размер

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то boolean занимает в памяти только один байт

Comment: Ладно, спасибо..

Comment: При двух вызовах за очень короткое время будет веселый race condition.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, но только если будет два UI потока. а второй UI поток в WPF нельзя просто так взять и запустить

Comment: @PashaPash: это хорошо. А еще, кстати, не хватает кое-чего при закрытии окна. )

Comment: @andrew В Prism есть интерфейс INavigationAware предназначенный как раз для таких случаев. Если ViewModel его реализует, то ViewModel в методе bool IsNavigationTarget сама определяет нужно ли открывать еще одно окно. Это если вы используете Prism - архитектуру.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать базовый класс для всех окон. В нем создать свойство, которое будет отвечать за состояние окна и изменять его в зависимости от Открытия/Закрытия. Все окна унаследовать от него.

Второй способ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202101/how-do-i-know-if-a-wpf-window-is-opened):

```
public static bool IsWindowOpen<T>(string name = "") where T : Window
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        ? Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any()
        : Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any(w => w.Name.Equals(name));
}
```

использовать так:

```
if (Helpers.IsWindowOpen<MyWindow>())
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для WPF можно проверить следующим образом:

```
public void OpenNewWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Window win in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        // Окно закрыто - открываем
        if ((win.IsLoaded == false)  && (win.Title == Window2.Title))
        {
            Window2.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
            Window2.Show();
            return;
        }
    }
    // Окно открыто - действуем по необходимости
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаете в коде главной формы переменную
`public static bool peremennaya;`
Устанавливаете эвент на загрузку главной формы(Делается из окна редактора как на картинке)[image: здесь]

После двойного шелчка вас кинет в код формы там задаете в эвенте значение этой переменной

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//Код нашей переменной
        peremennaya = false;
    }
```

После переходим к дочернему окну задаем эвент FormClosing
[image: FormClosing тут]
после чего пишем туда

```
MainForm.peremennaya = true;
```

"MainForm"-Это название нашего главного окна где мы задали переменную.
После создаем эвент кнопки (кликая по ней 2 раза) и пишем следующее

```
 ChildWindow child = new ChildWindow();           
        if (peremennaya == false)
        {
            child.Show();
        }      
        else if (peremennaya == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString("Не удалось открыть форму"));
        }
```

"ChildWindow"-Это дочернее окно открываемого из главного "MainForm".
У меня лично это работает при том что у меня для запуска этого окна есть еще и условия, я просто при несоответствии условиям оставлял переменную как false.